# Playing audio file in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I got stuck with one requirement i need to play a media file in android.I will post the screen shot of the page

[image: Playing the media file]

Actual requirement is the user wants to play the audio file in his recordings list.The recordings list are shown through list adapter.I want to display the play progress of the audio file  on the same page(as like shown in the screen shot).

Iam pasting the code which i have tried.

```
public class RecordingActivity extends ListActivity implements MediaPlayerControl {
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    MediaController mMediaController;
    Handler mHandler;
    String OUTPUT_FILE;
    RelativeLayout rl; 
    Context context = null;
    Point p;
    static final String[] recordings = new String[] {"Example1","Example2",
            "Example3","Example4","Example5" };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new FirstAdapter(this, recordings));
        }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        showPopup(RecordingActivity.this, p); 
        // get selected items
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(RecordingActivity.this);
        OUTPUT_FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/recorder.mp3";
        try{
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(OUTPUT_FILE);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();

        }
        catch(Exception e){


        }
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                       mMediaController.show(10000);
                       mMediaPlayer.start();
                       mMediaController.setEnabled(true);
                     }
             });            
            }
        });
    }
    private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {
       int popupWidth = 200;
       int popupHeight = 150;
     // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
       RelativeLayout viewGroup = (RelativeLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.reviewlist);
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
       .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_play, viewGroup);
     // Creating the PopupWindow
       final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
       popup.setContentView(layout);
       popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
       popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
       popup.setFocusable(true);
       // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
       int OFFSET_X = 30;
       int OFFSET_Y = 30;
       // Clear the default translucent background
       popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
       // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
       popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY,p.x+OFFSET_X,p.y+OFFSET_Y);
       // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
       ImageButton close = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
       Button b1 =(Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
       Button b2 =(Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button2);
       close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          popup.dismiss();
        }
       });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
    }




 @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override    
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        int percentage = (mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() * 100) / mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
        return percentage;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
      if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
       mMediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int pos) {
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaController.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mMediaController.show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem am facing is i am able to play the audio file ,but it is not showing any popup layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Media player**

```
   MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

 // Set data source -
  setDataSource("/sdcard/path_to_song");

 // Play audio
 mp.start();

// Pause audio
mp.pause();

   // Reset mediaplayer
  mp.reset();

  // Get song length duration - in milliseconds
 mp.getDuration();

  // Get current duration - in milliseconds
 mp.getCurrentDuration();

   // Move song to particular second - used for Forward or Backward
  mp.seekTo(positon); // position in milliseconds

  // Check if song is playing or not
 mp.isPlaying(); // returns true or false
```

Hope this will give you some solution. Refer this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/). It will solve your problem

Comment: Your answer is about simple media player.This is not relevant to my question which i have posted.

Answer (score 3):

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(PlayAudioActivity.this);
        mMediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.audioView));

        String audioFile = "" ; 
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFile);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println("Error in playing audio");
        }

        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                    mMediaController.show(10000);
                                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                            }
                    });
            }
        });
    }
```

if you have done this then.

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
    }




 @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override    
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        int percentage = (mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() * 100) / mMediaPlayer.getDuration();

        return percentage;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int pos) {
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mMediaController.show();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait i am updating once it is gud i will consider your soln as accepted ok

Comment: i am having some doubts can u please clarify 1.is the activity implements any listener 2.you are adding view right is that layout or any widget or else please post the entire code so tht i can understand in a better manner.Thanks in advance

Comment: as like in screen shot i have added relative layout in that i have added buttons as the child.that is not showing

Comment: ok. probel is that you are write code same code as i send to you but you have to put this code when your popup is startd.. at that time willl work

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PlayAudioActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayerControl {
        private MediaController mMediaController;
        private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

use this .